# Combine Sublists in Dart

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart

Is there a way to combine Sublists depends on its values.

eg.

**What I have**

```
list1 = [obj1,obj2]
list2 = [obj3,obj4]
list3 = [list1,list2]
```

**What I want**

```
list4 = [obj1,obj4]   //condition ->   obj1.isValid == true && obj4.isValid == true
```

is there a method in list3 eg. list3.combine(...) ???

I know i can reduce the list with list.where((obj) => obj.isValid) but how can I combine the lists in one step.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

```
list4 = list3.expand((lists) => lists).toList().where((obj) => obj.isValid).toList();
```